# Which C++ data structure should I use for end-only access and no relocations?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have an unusual set of requirements for my C++ application. I need a container that:

- Is generic, like `std::vector`
- Can have elements added to the end
- Can have elements removed from the end
- Never moves the memory location of elements
- Does *not* need to provide general purpose access to elements (I keep pointers for this)
- Takes ownership over its elements.

Is there a data-structure with these properties?

Comment: `std::list<std::shared_ptr<T>>` / `std::list<std::unique_ptr<T>>` ? Your *ownsership requirement* and "I keep pointers for this" feels weird together

Comment: what about `std::vector` with a huge enough `reserve` on construction ?

Comment: if you don't need this structure to be searchable particularly then a lot of the usual considerations go away. why not list or vector of smart pointers?

Comment: @Fureeish Yes, it is weird but it is an important optimization

Comment: so is there something wrong with `std::list<std::shared_ptr<T>>`?

Comment: @sdgfsdh: "*it is an important optimization*" I'm curious as to what kind of optimization you could possibly get out of this. It doesn't sound like you want a *container* at all.

Comment: use a queue. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/

Comment: @VidorVistrom: A `std::queue` is not a container; it's a container adapter. Equally importantly, a queue is FIFO; he explicitly wants LIFO. That would be a *stack*.

Comment: @Fureeish What would be the advantage of `std::list<std::shared_ptr<T>>` over just `std::list<T>` in this case?

Comment: isn't it a [stack](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) that matches your requirements:

> `std::deque` (double-ended queue) is an indexed sequence container that allows fast insertion and deletion at both its beginning and its end. In addition, insertion and deletion at either end of a deque never invalidates pointers or references to the rest of the elements.

Also, `std::list`.

Comment: `std::deque` will reallocate the memory

Comment: @Fureeish: No, it will not. Not if you only add to the beginning or end. That's why it is called a *double ended* queue.

Comment: `std::deque` is correct, since I am only ever adding and removing from the end.